# Why these two field extension have the same index?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $h:C\rightarrow C'$ be a nonconstant morphism between two algebraic curves $C,C'$over $k$, and let $h^*:\bar{k}(C')\rightarrow \bar{k}(C)$ be the pullback of $h$ given by $f\mapsto f\circ h$.

My question is, why the following holds:

$$
[k(C):h^*(k(C'))]=[\bar{k}(C):h^*(\bar{k}(C'))]?
$$